# Как найти простые натуральные числа из диапазона?

Tags: javascript, циклы

Не понимаю как поставить циклы так, чтобы число, проходя второй for полностью до конца, попадало в массив. До конца, то есть у него не было ни с одним числом остатка от деления 0.

```
let arr = [];
for(let i = 2; i <= 10; i++){
    for(g = 2; g < i; g++){
        if (i % g !== 0) arr.push(i);
    }
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let n = prompt("введите границу диапазона");
for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    let flag=1;
    for (let j = 2; (j <= i/2)&&(flag==1); j++) {
        if (i%j==0) {
            flag=0
        }
    }
    if (flag==1) {
        console.log(i);
    }

}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Вижу даже успешно сделал оптимизации! Вопрос - нужно ли делать проверку на четные числа больше 2-х? К примеру имеет ли смысл переменную j делать 10 или 18? Задание на будущее: разберись как сделать досрочное покидание цикла и как сделать досрочный переход на следующую итерацию цикла. В остальном - молодец.

Answer (score 1):

Понимаю - учеба началась!

Пожалуйста, сделай отдельную функцию, которая принимает на вход число, проверяет его на простоту и возвращает True или False.

После этого, надеюсь, станет понятнее?

Делать цикл в цикле можно, но это может усложнять понимание текста. В твоем случае нужно как только встречаем (i % g == 0) мы досрочно покидаем цикл. Если цикл полностью выполнен и условие не срабатывало, то добавляем число в массив.

Comment: Не знаю на сколько правильно понял, но получилось сделать так, и похоже всё работает, однако числа, которые прошли все итерации в массив клонируются... Можно ли это на месте решить как-то, или отдельную конструкцию делать чтобы дубликаты убирать все?

<code>
let arr = [];
for(let i = 2; i <= 20; i++){
    for(g = 2; g < i; g++){
        if (i % g === 0) break;
        arr.push(i);
    }
}
console.log(arr);
</code>

Comment: Плохо. С досрочным покиданием не получается? Вводим переменную allGood и перед циклом проверки на простоту присваиваем ей True. Если встречается if (i % g === 0) то делаем allGood = False. Дальше рассказывать? Легче сделать отдельную функцию проверки на простоту.

Comment: да.. Пожалуйста, сложно что-то

Comment: досрочный переход на следующую итерацию цикла - это continue, как я понимаю. Но преподаватель запрещает нам его использовать..